# How do I figure out what "challenges/issues" my character could encounter/go through?

Tags: creative-writing, plot, character-development, dramatic-writing

I will supply you with some character information and some context for my specific project, though I'm thinking my question could be relevant for almost any story.

I am writing a story involving with a "bad boy" main character "**X**" (hero) and a female character "**Y**" (to-be heroine). I have a clear idea of the hero and his place in society: Very wealthy for his age (inherited fathers company). Perceived as somewhat of a womanizer, In my opinion he's misunderstood. I plan for the two characters to fall in love at a later point in the story. Before that however, I want the hero to go through some challenges/struggles before eventually ending up with the heroine.

As of now, there are some "romantic" issues: "**X**" has an affaire with B, B is separated from C, C is interested in "**Y**" and "**Y**" is also being charmed by ex-boyfriend E..

Aside from the romantic issues, I'm having trouble coming up with challenges/issues that make sense for the hero to go through/solve.

So; I am not looking for answers regarding my specific plot, but rather a broader answer to the question:

**How do I figure out what challenges fit a character?**

Comment: This is a "what to write" question, even broadly. Honestly, it sounds like you have a character in search of a story. So either write plotless character sketches because you're in love with the guy, or find a story idea whether it fits him or not.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum, if it asked for specific ideas, I would agree. But it asks for the types of issues a character can face, and that is a question that can be answered in a general way that is useful to others.

Comment: Brittany Wright and Mark Baker each make excellent points, supporting each other, but I would add a theory to your specific issue, which could be relevant for other writers. 

I've recently contemplated whether or not my main character was actually my main character (or one of them), and I realized that even though I had a good IDEA of him, I didn't actually KNOW him. Now, I'm very new to writing and creating characters, and aware that different writers work differently, but for me, this helped: Write something else about him. The more you write about him the more you actually KNOW him.

Comment: OP, for this to be on-topic here, we're going to want to identify what, specifically, is giving you trouble -- rather than simply describing the situation and telling us you're stuck. Can you tell us: **(1)** What's your purpose in "introducing problems"? What are you trying to achieve with that? What would make a potential problem a "good" one, and what makes ones you've maybe already come up with ("maybe he gets kidnapped by aliens!" :P) "not good enough"?

Comment: And **(2)** Is there something _specific_ about the bad-boy archetype that's making this hard for you? Could you come up with problems for a different character?

Comment: I agree with @MarkBaker in this case. I don't think this question should be closed, as I have struggled with a similar issue and was going to post the comment above as an answer, since I'm in the process of answering this for my self and believe others could benefit from it. Continuing where I left off: Once you know the character(s) intimately, you feel what he(they) feel(s) and understand what kinds of struggles would make sense and what challenges would "develop the hero" and help progress and natural flow of the story. As Brittany mentions: Background is relevant for future issues.

Comment: Also: when referring to the heroine and the hero, what makes them special?  Are there simply the main characters (why?) or do they posses unique traits or abilities that make it obvious that they play the roles they do? If you are unsure of what "should" happen to the "hero", maybe he's not actually the hero (or main character) see here: http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/26309/how-do-i-know-whos-my-protagonist-early-in-writing-process-maybe-complicated

Comment: I have edited the question in an attempt to keep it on topic while still ensuring that the given answers make sense. This is my first edit, so it may not be accepted, but I thought I'd give it a try, since I felt that the more general question was useful.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum My question was kindly edited by storbror and I believe it is now on-topic for this website.

Comment: It really isn't. The more restrictions you put on and details you add (He's a "bad boy," he's a womanizer, he's misunderstood, there's a female love interest, there's an affair, there's a love triangle...), the more specific it becomes. This cannot be on-topic with any of these elements. If you want to start over with a fresh question of "I have a character with pre-determined characteristics" — and **you don't list any of them** — "but I don't know how to use those characteristics to create challenges and thereby a plot," then that would be on-topic.

Comment: The issue is that a question must be applicable to other people using other characters. Your question must *also* be helpful to someone creating a paladin, a weaselly criminal, a bored socialite, a clever detective, a mercenary, a courtesan, or a sheltered child-wizard. Otherwise, it's too local, it's just about your character and your plot, and it's off-topic.

Comment: Another option is explaining what you've already tried. If you're having trouble coming up with issues _for these particular characters_, tell us what that trouble is -- what you've tried, and why you're not happy with it. That's likely to be specific enough for us to be helpful with :) On the other hand, if you're having trouble coming up with issues _for characters in general_, then the particular characters really aren't relevant at all.

Answer (score 5):

As Anne Lamott would say, we all have our own "mental illnesses", and they usually stem from our experiences. If your hero is a "bad boy" who inherited a bunch of money, has a company, and who seems to have a thing for the secretary, consider how these aspects of his life came to be: If he inherited money from his father, would that affect him positively or negatively? Would he invest carefully, or blow it all on his wants rather than his needs? Would he take responsibility, or dodge it and thus incur the wrath of others?

Going further into his past, you can consider how his childhood caused certain "bad boy" problems in his adult life. If his dad was off making money, did he have time for his son? Did the son (ie. your hero) begin to act out to get Dad's attention? Did that carry over into his adult life? I find that character's internal issues usually create external problems for them. If you let your bad boy hero act the fool, he might get into trouble with someone else and, by consequence, help the story progress.

Answer (score 3):

The basic shape of any character's story arc is that they want something and there are forces that make it difficult for them to get it. They try the least expensive thing they can to achieve their desire, and are rebuffed. They then try the next least expensive thing and are rebuffed again. This repeats until we get to the climax where we discover just how much they are willing to give -- how much they are willing to bleed -- to achieve their desire.

The issues that a character goes through are therefore driven by their desire. They are all about their attempt to get what they want and the things that prevent them from getting it. So the first question you have to ask yourself is, what does my character want? What is the desire that drives him towards the climax of this story?